# Передать widget в другой класс

Tags: qt, c++

Есть класс downloader и есть класс data.
Нужно передать downloader у data, чтобы из data вызвать функцию, которая у downloader.

Пробовал через сигналы, но так получается, что метод сигнала дублируется у файле moc.

```
multiple definition
```

Когда я наследую public QObject, если просто Object, то ошибка получается, когда connect делаю:

```
'QObject' is an inaccessible base of 'data'
     connect(downloader, SIGNAL(authed()), this, SLOT(auth__()) );
                                                        ^
```

вопрос решен